# Is there a way to cycle through variables? (C++)

Tags: c++, class

I am creating a class with 18 different variables, most of them doubles. I need to declare all of them and also perform the same operation on each of them. Is there any way to use a loop to cycle through all the declarations?
For example, instead of saying:

`double a = 0.0;`

`double b = 0.0;`

`double c = 0.0;`

...

`double z = 0.0;`

Is it possible to loop them like this:

```
while(variables are undefined)

define the next undefined variable

end loop
```

EDIT: Thank you for the answers, everyone. I didn't want to use an array at first because it would make remembering which element represents what value more difficult. I will look into map, and if that doesn't work I think I found a way to organize the array that I can remember.

Comment: Why dont use arrays?

Comment: do you have any code you have tried that might not work? but like people are saying try array or vectors or list.   Array's Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/  Vectors: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: If you use a std::map, you can use character/string names as indices, emulating your variable names. And if the variable names are in a sequence, like ASCII 'a'-'z', you can easily loop through the map indices and initialize.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using variables all of the same type, and you know how many you need, you can use an array to store the values and then access them using a loop.

For example:

```
double dbl_values[18];
for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    dbl_values[i] = something; // Define variables here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, it's best to use an array or vector in C++ like so:

#### Using a Vector:

```
std::vector<double> MyVector;
//Use 'push_back' to add values to the vector
MyVector.push_back(0.00);
```

To perform an operation on all the values in your vector, you can do this:

```
for (auto& i : MyVector)
    someOperation(i);
```

In your case, we're adding elements, so we can use a loop like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) 
    MyVector.push_back(some_value);
```

#### Using an Array:

If you know how many values you're going to need, you could also use a fixed array like so (otherwise it's generally easier to use a vector):

```
double MyArray[20] = {0}; //Creates an array of 20 doubles and sets them all to 0

//We can set individual values using the [] operator:
MyArray[0] = 2.3; //This sets the first element to 2.3
```

Performing an operation on the array's elements is similar to what we did with the vector:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) 
    someOperation(MyArray[i]);
```

Similarly, for defining arrays with a loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) 
    MyArray[i] = some_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `map` or an `array`/`vector`. You can loop through them by using those.

Comment: let's not forget iterators!

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to try this:

```
double double_values[18];
for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42: OP is saying like this, "`I am creating a class with 18 different variables`".

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to change your struct, leave them as variables and make a `vector` of pointers to them:

```
class foo{
public:
foo(){
    all.push_back(&a);
    all.push_back(&b);
    ...
    all.push_back(&z);
}
std::vector<double*> all; 
private:
double a,b,c,...z;

};
```

and then you can sth like:

```
int main(){
    foo f;
    for(auto& i:f.all){
        *i=0.0;
    }
}
```